# Using multiple conditions in ternary operator to stop rendering component on specific routs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have a component - side menu. I want to have it on all pages except singIn and singUp page. The way I choose to do it is to use "useLocation" and check location.pathname before rendering component. It looks something like that:

```
let location = useLocation().pathname;
  return (
location !== '/signin' && '/signup' ? (
  <div>sidemenu</div>
) : (
  <>
  </>
)
```

But it works only with first statement. Is it possible to pass multiple statements? Or may be there is another method not to render component on two/three specific pages ?

Comment: See the result of `location !== '/signin' && '/signup'` using `console.log`

Comment: You want `location !== '/signin' && location !== '/signup'` not `location !== '/signin' && '/signup'`

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Any boolean expression is valid in a ternary.

However, `location !== '/signin' && '/signup'` is parsed like:

```
(location !== '/signin') && ('/signup')
```

So you should instead write:

```
`location !== '/signin' && location !== '/signup'
```

---

Also, instead of the syntax

```
(expression) ? (
  <div>sidemenu</div>
) : (
  <>
  </>
)
```

if you don't want anything to be rendered in the `false` case, you can just use:

```
return (expression) && (<div>sidemenu</div>)
```

which will return `false` and not render anything if the expression is false, or if the expression is true it will render your div.

---

Also, a nice syntax for checking lists of path names is to use `includes`, like so:

```
['/signin', '/signup'].includes(useLocation().pathname)
```

then you have a one-liner that is easily extensible if you decide you want to add another path